# MS Dynamics CRM 2013 Email to Case drop to same case

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am using MS Dynamics CRM 2013 SP1,
I used the "Automatic Case Creation Rules" to manage automatic case creation for emails

The steps are more or less like [this](http://blog.customereffective.com/blog/2014/06/dynamics-crm-spring-14-email-to-case.html)

After the setup, I tried to send emails to the specify queue, the first email is perfectly created with correct setting. But then I sent another email to the same queue with exactly the same email subject but different content, what I expected is a new case will be created for the new email, however, the result let me down, the email drop into the case created by the first email.

In the real situation, customer will send email to us often with same email subject, but it should be in different cases, I am not sure if my setting got something wrong.

As I don't have enough reputation to post images,
I will just describe it in text

- I ticked "Create cases for email for unknown senders"
- I leave it blank "Create case if a valid entitlement exists for the
  customer"
- I ticked "Create cases for activities associated with a resolved
  case"
- I set "Create case when the case associated with the activity is
  resolved since ***1 minute***"

Specify Case Details:

Condition : Email Regarding Does Not Contain Data

- Case Properties : System Create to "Yes",
- Status Reason to "New",
- Team to "Support Team",
- Case Title to *"Same as Email Subject"*

I am glad to have someone who can help to solve the problem, 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved.

Go to Settings > Email Configuration > Email Configuration Settings

uncheck "Use Smart Matching"